# In Opengl perspective projection , can NearPlane distance be calculated out by FOV?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, glm-math, perspectivecamera

When FOV and distance are certain FarPlane's radius can be calculated out by tan . As we all know the final cramped value is between -1 and 1 , so according to radius/1 = far_distance/near_distance , the near_distance is easy to get . No . We can even straightly get it via 1/tan .
So why it's necessary in glm::perspective to provide a nearplane distance ? What if the input nearplane distance is less or more than the calculated technical distance ?

Comment: Please elaborate how you came to radius/1 = far_distance/near_distance. I'm not sure how radius (which is usually in the screenspace x-y plane) relates to the z value range

Comment: @BDL Radius is referred to the far plane being its 1/2 width . There are two similar triangles starting separately from far_distance and near_distance , erecting radius and  1 as its vertical edge. The farplane is projected onto the nearplane so near_vertical_edge =1(ndc )

Comment: I am feeling like I've found the answer. Probably the near plane is not receiving others' projection. Anyway , I think , similar to orthogonal projection , there must be a plane receiving projection, rather than a singular point . If near_distance is free from FOV , then this receiving plane is probably between the two clipping plane. However, in this case how to cast things behind of it on it？

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand your point. Usually, near_plane and far_plane in a perspective projection describe the distance of the near/far plane from the projection center. So 1/2 width of the far plane is something like `far_plane * tan(fov)` and that's almost always not 1.0 in camera space. It's true that it gets mapped to 1.0 after projection and homogeneous divide, but near_plane, far_plane are usually defined in camera space, not NDC. Do you maybe have a drawing of what you mean?

Comment: Ah no . It's just my understanding . I was trying to understand my tutorial . So camera space is a world rotated , transformed ...... Then near plane and far plane receive a original 3d coordinative value as distance . Thanks . It's getting much more clear now .

Comment: I was meaning , which should be described like that according to FOV and far plane we can calculate where the projected plane is . As I thought it as the projected plane was just the near plane .

Comment: Actually I'm coding a shader now . So I see z/w determines how much it's long from the projection center to the projected plane , which should be a depth value . I was always thinking z/w a constant , in the case the projected plane were just the near plane . The radius is obviously not always w so the projected plane is actually moving , and not the near plane